# Custom ValidationMessageFor Template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 right now with unobtrusive jquery client validation.

By default, ValidationMessageFor generates a span tag with certain classes and attributes set. I would like it to generate a different template instead. For example, I might want a div tag with a certain background image.

Is this possible at all, or can I just obtain the plain text error message from there so I can do my own styling?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 2, the `span` is hard coded. There is no way to use a `div` instead with `ValidationMessageFor`.

You can get the message similar to how the built-in helper does it:

```
if (modelError != null) {
    builder.SetInnerText(GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, modelState));
}

    private static string GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(HttpContextBase httpContext, ModelError error, ModelState modelState) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage)) {
            return error.ErrorMessage;
        }
        if (modelState == null) {
            return null;
        }

        string attemptedValue = (modelState.Value != null) ? modelState.Value.AttemptedValue : null;
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, GetInvalidPropertyValueResource(httpContext), attemptedValue);
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tried the code above, but it seems to be the server side validation. I'm doing a client side validation with the jquery unobtrusive validation library, which has a completely different implementation.

Comment: No, that's incorrect on a couple different counts.  Server and client validation is not a "completely different implementation." They both come out of `ValidationMessageFor`. Please feel free to refer to the source code. You can change the default validation message in, e.g., the jQuery validator, but that won't do the `span` -> `div` which was also part of your question.

Comment: Right. What I really wanted to question was whether this will change from span to div when I do the client side validation. My guess is that you probably have to have a complete different implementation for the client side in javascript, unless of course the above code auto-generates javascript templates of ValidationMessageFor for both server-side and client side. Doing it just in one place is incomplete. So this code should probably happen as well.

Comment: You really should look at the code yourself. It generates (1) server-side error, if any (2) placeholder for client validation message (3) metadata for JavaScript validator (4) prompt text for user (e.g. `*` by a required field) all in one method.